# Solve the equation $y' + (xy)^2 = -2/(x^4)$ knowing that $y_1 = 1/(x^3)$ is the particular solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$y' + (xy)^2 = -\frac2{x^4}\text{ with }y_1 = \frac1{x^3}$$

I have tried using various differential equations methods to solve but it appears to be very challenging.

Comment: Hence you stated that you *"have tried using various differential equations methods"* include what you have **actually done**. It is way easier to spot mistakes when we can see what you have really tried.

Comment: $y_1$ is not a solution   maybe you have a typo ?

Comment: Y1 = 1/(x^3) is the particular solution, therefore what i tried was:

Comment: y' + (xy)^2 = 0 , which is the homogeneous part of the equation, to find the complementary solution but seeing that the this equation is not linear, how would i then approach it ?

Comment: you can't do that it's not linear

Comment: Differntial equations of the type $y'+p(x)y+q(x)y^n=0$ are called [Bernoulli equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation) and can be solved by making the substitution $z=\frac1{y^{n-1}}$ and $z'=-(n-1)\frac{y'}{y^n}$ respectively. But this aproach will fail. Therefore consider the given equation as [Ricatti equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation)

Comment: Further @ImmanuelShifidi are you sure about your whole equation? The general solution, given by [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27%2B(x*y)%5E2%3D2%2Fx%5E2), is quite complicated and does not look very nice.

Answer (score 1):

Your differential equation is a [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation). The general form of this type is given by
$$y'+p(x)y+q(x)y^2=r(x)$$
The attempt is to set $y=y_1(x)+v(x)$ where $y_1(x)$ is a particular solution. In your case choose $y=\frac1{x^3}+v(x)$ and plug this in your equation. Considering $p(x)=x^2,q(x)=1$ and $r(x)=-\frac2{x^2}$ this yields to an ODE in $v(x)$ an just evaluate $y$ afterwards by adding the particular solution.

But there is a problem in your case; your given $y_1$ does not fulfill the DE since one would get

$$\begin{align}
\left(-\frac3{x^4}\right)+\left(\frac{x}{x^3}\right)^2=\frac1{x^4}-\frac3{x^4}=-\frac{2}{x^4}\ne-\frac2{x^2}
\end{align}$$

Therefore $y_1=\frac1{x^3}$ would be a solution if and only if the RHS is given by $-\frac2{x^4}$.

---

For clarification we are dealing with the following problem

> $$y'+(xy)^2=-\frac2{x^4}\text{ with }y_1=\frac1{x^3}$$

Hence this DE is a Ricatti equation we make the attempt $y=y_1(x)+v(x)$ with the given particular solution. Plugging $y$ and $y'$ within the equation yields to

$$\begin{align}
\left(\frac1{x^3}+v(x)\right)'+\left(\frac1{x^2}+xv(x)\right)^2&=-\frac2{x^4}\\
-\frac3{x^4}+v'(x)+\frac1{x^4}+x^2v^2(x)+2\frac{v(x)}x&=-\frac2{x^4}\\
v'(x)+2\frac{v(x)}x+x^2v^2(x)&=0
\end{align}$$

The last equation is now a Bernoulli equation therefore we divide by $-v^2(x)$ perform the substitution $z=\frac1{v(x)}$ and $z'=-\frac{v'(x)}{v^2(x)}$ to get

$$\begin{align}
v'(x)+2\frac{v(x)}x+x^2v^2(x)&=0\\
\Leftrightarrow -\frac{v'(x)}{v^2(x)}-2\frac1{xv(x)}-x^2&=0\\
\Leftrightarrow z'-2\frac zx-x^2&=0\\
\end{align}$$

The last equation is a simple ODE in $z$ and can be solved by standard techniques. I will leave to you to verify that one will get

$$z=cx^2+x^3\Rightarrow v(x)=\frac1{cx^2+x^3}$$

and so we finally get

$$y=y_1+v(x)=\frac1{x^3}+\frac1{cx^2+x^3}$$

as the general solution.

Comment: how comes $1/x^3$ is  a particular solution ??

Comment: @Isham He wrote $y_1=\frac1{x^3}$. Although this does not solve the equation the general approach is given by this method.

Comment: ok @mrtaurho ....

Comment: I realized now that the equation is supposed to be y' + (xy)^2 = -2/(x^2), would that make a difference ?

Comment: @ImmanuelShifidi As long as you did not change the partiular solution $y_1$ no. The [general solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+y%27%2B(x*y)%5E2%3D-2%2Fx%5E2) is still quite complex. The LHS is given by $-\frac2{x^4}$ for $y_1=\frac1{x^3}$ regardless of the RHS. But anyway change it within your question.

Comment: If the y1 does not satisfy the DE, is the problem then with the equation ?

Comment: Isnt the general solution supposed to be in the form of y= y1 + 1/v(x) or is my equation a special case ?

Comment: @ImmanuelShifidi I would say yes. Take a look at the general solution computed by WolframAlpha. Within these solutions your particular solution does not appear which is in contrast to the assumption to solve these equations by setting $y=y_1(x)+v(x)$. Since of the complexity of the general solution to your given DE I would guess the error lies indeed within the equation. As I mentioned in my answer if the RHS is given by $\frac{-1}{x^4}$ $y_1$ is a solution; but only in this case. The general form should be $y=y_1+v(x)$ not $y=y_1+\color{red}{\frac1{v(x)}}$.

Comment: What the equation is in this form, y' + (xy)^2 = -2/(x^4) ?

Comment: No. Your given equation is $y'+(xy)^2=\color{red}{\frac{-2}{x^2}}$ and **not** $y'+(xy)^2=\color{red}{\frac{-2}{x^4}}$. Maybe a typo you still did not corrected? For the case that the RHS is $\frac{-1}{x^4}$ the general solution is $y=\frac1{cx^2+x^3}+\frac1{x^3}$ which can be obtained by using the Ricatti equation algorithm. I can add it wihtin my answer if you want me to?

Comment: I actually made another mistake in the equation sir.

Comment: @ImmanuelShifidi Ah, okay :) Make sure that everything is correct *before* you post your question ^^

Comment: Yes please add it

Answer (score 1):

Equations of the type
$$
y'+(xy)^2=ax^b
$$
have solutions of the form $y=cx^d$ if
$$
cdx^{d-1}+c^2x^{2d+2}=ax^b
$$
This requires all three exponents to be equal, $d-1=2d+2=b$, so that $d=-3$, $b=-4$. Then necessarily $a=c(c-3)$, which with the choice $c=1$ gives $a=-2$, as you finally gave in the correction of your equation.

---

Sometimes increasing the order leads to an easier to solve problem, if there is a nice solution at all. So set $y=\frac{u'}{x^2u}$, then 
$$
-\frac2{x^4}=y'+(xy)^2=\frac{u''}{x^2u}-\frac{2u'}{x^3u}-\frac{u'^2}{x^2u^2}+\frac{u'^2}{x^2u^2}
\implies
x^2u''-2xu'+2u=0
$$
which indeed has easy solutions, for instance as Euler-Cauchy DE. You also know that $u_1=x$ is one solution, so that you can use order reduction.